# Vue adding dynamic class doesn't change current class

Tags: css, vue.js

I have wrapper div with padding and I am dynamically adding items inside of it.
I don't want any padding on wrapper div when there is no item in it.

I have created computed method `isEmpty` to check if there are items or not and used it to add optional class  `:class={ className: isEmpty }` but it doesn't work.

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/2u9rtdmh/3/

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap an expression for `:class` into `"`:

```
:class="{ className: isEmpty }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the console errors when trying to diagnose problems, i.e. your jsfiddle doesn't even have an `#app` element.

The correct syntax for your scenario would be `:class="{ 'padding0' : isEmpty }"`

[Binding HTML Classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes)

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  },
  computed: {
    isEmpty() {
     return true;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.my-wrapper {
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: white;
}

.padding0 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <div :class="{ 'padding0' : isEmpty }" class="my-wrapper">
     <div>
       <div>
         
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```